# Editable internally, but still viewable outside?

Tags: c#, keyword, readonly, internal

In my C# DLL, I want the properties to be readable to outside applications, but not editable. Kind of like a combination of `readonly` and `internal` - `readonly` to outside applications and `internal` to the DLL.

But the problem I have with `readonly` is that you can't edit them as you please.

And the problem I have with `internal` is that it completely hides the properties to outside programs.

Is it possible to solve this dilemma? I'm open to anything, honestly.

Comment: The `accesibility` tag is about helping people with disabilities. (Tag removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using properties, you can use different access modifiers for the `get` and `set` methods:

```
public T MyProperty { get; internal set; }
```

You could also use the other access modifiers for `set`, such as `private` or `protected`, depending on your use case.
If you have a different set up (like an internal field) you could also expose a public getter for the field:

```
public T MyProperty { get { return myInternalField; } }
```

Comment: I settled on {get; internal set;} - thank you for introducing me to this

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your `internal` variables with `readonly` versions? Then external clients only see the `readonly` versions.

(I'm assuming these variables are Properties?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using properties try doing the following:

```
public string Example {get; protected set; }
```

or

```
public string Example {get; private set; }
```

The first will allow the property to be set by sub classes while the second won't. This will allow you to set the property inside the class but users of the dll will be able to access the property as read only. You can also add internal methods so that other classes can modify that state within the DLL but anybody referencing it will not be able to.

Comment: I settled on {get; internal set;} - thank you for introducing me to this